# How to make pg-promise return rows as arrays?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

How can we make [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) return an array of rows from a query, as opposed to array of row objects?

Comment: Do you have any example of what you want to ?

Comment: @hud if my answer is what you needed, then please acknowledge so.

Answer (score 7):

[pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) supports advanced parameters for `Prepared Statements` and `Parameterized Queries`, exactly as they are in [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres). One such parameter - [rowMode](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html#rowMode), can be set to `array` to make the driver return rows as arrays.

```
// Prepared Statement:
await db.any({
    name: 'my-prep-statement',
    text: 'select ...', // a query or a QueryFile object (see PreparedStatement)
    values: [],
    rowMode: 'array'
});

// Parameterized Query:
await db.any({
    text: 'select ...', // a query or a QueryFile object (see ParameterizedQuery)
    values: [],
    rowMode: 'array'
});
```

See also types that wrap them: [PreparedStatement](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html) and [ParameterizedQuery](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/ParameterizedQuery.html).

The code below is equivalent to the one above, but offers better performance + re-usability + flexibility of setting values separately.

```
const ps = new pgp.PreparedStatement({
    name: 'my-prep-statement',
    text: 'select ...', // a query or a QueryFile object (see PreparedStatement)
    values: [], // alternatively, can be set when calling a query method
    rowMode: 'array'
});

await db.any(ps);

const pq = new pgp.ParameterizedQuery({
    text: 'select ...', // a query or a QueryFile object (see ParameterizedQuery)
    values: [], // alternatively, can be set when calling a query method
    rowMode: 'array'
});

await db.any(pq);
```

Comment: Just a little problem on the code above.
You forgot to call pgp. before loading the method.
var pq = new pgp.ParameterizedQuery