# Same name attributes in select list in pg-promise

Tags: pg-promise

Is it possible to get the same name attributes in the select list (as JSON deduplicates them)?
For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id int;
);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(2);
CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id int;
);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1);

SELECT *
  FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id

should return:

id id 
-----
1   1
2   null


but will return instead:

id
---
1
null
```

I'm trying to build a web-based SQL editor, and this is kind of a showstopper.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020663/how-to-make-pg-promise-return-rows-as-arrays

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, found it, it was solved in:

- pg: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/393
- and subsequently in pg-promise: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.4.0.5

One can use rowMode argument to get results as an array:
http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html#rowMode